# How to call or attach js function on "onblur" of input in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-events

I am trying to call a function on `onblur` event of a textbox. I tried calling it inline but that didn't work so I added all the js in a separate file and tried to add `EventListener` on the textbox but that's not working. Here is my code. This is how my js starts:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    document.getElementById("Ex").addEventListener("onblur", function(){
        CalculateTax();
    });   
});    

function CalculateTax() {   
    /// Code
}
```

Comment: You can use js and jQuery in-line on WordPress pages. If it is not working it is because you've done something wrong. But, you have not provided enough information to work that out.

Comment: actually when I try to call the function from adding onblur inline in the "text" option it just disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try adding event listener in following manner:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       jQuery(document).on("blur", "#Ex", function(){
           CalculateTax();
       });
   });
```